# gcloud build requires "serviceusage.services.use", but i already have owner role

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to submit a build using this command in the gcloud CLI:

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
```

but it returns this error:

> (gcloud.builds.submit) The user is forbidden from accessing the bucket
> [fastapi-api_cloudbuild]. Please check your organization's policy or
> if the user has the "serviceusage.services.use" permission

I checked in the IAM admin panel and it says that my account has the owner role and that i have most permissions, and i authenticated in the gcloud cli, but i still get said error, i havent tried much since i have no idea what i could try since i already have the highest role. thank you.

Comment: Seems like there is a VPC SC Perimeter in the Storage API, have you already reviewed that?

Comment: hey @FerreginaPelona , i have no idea what that is, how do i review it?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/manage-service-perimeters#list-and-describe As well you ma need to make sure the Cloud Build Service account has access to the bucket, not your account

Comment: okay, i went on to the VPC Service Controls page, I dont have an organization, i just want to like upload a python api to gcloud, ive never used this before. it tells me i cant view it without an organisation and i dont want to create an organization.

Comment: If there are no perimeters then review that the Cloud Build Service Account has the right permissions

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issues (caused by the change of the billing account), and I fixed it by disabling Google Cloud Build API and re-enabling.

I used this commands:

`gcloud services disable cloudbuild.googleapis.com --project "my_project"`

`gcloud services enable cloudbuild.googleapis.com --project "my_project"`

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your project in the cli with `gcloud config set project <project>`?

[Otherwise the answer from this thread might help (billing).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68536433/unable-to-submit-build-to-cloud-build-due-to-permissions-error)

[or this one with Storage Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886335/gcp-cloud-run-error-the-user-is-forbidden-from-accessing-the-bucket)